# Select element by class name AND text content?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to select a div with class `mstrmojo-ListBox-item selected nAll` and content `Market Risk`. I tried this:

```
$("[class^='mstrmojo-ListBox-item']","div:contains('Market Risk')")
```

However it returns all the nodes with this class, like it omits the second argument.

```
var a = $("[nm='Sel_Team_ListB']")
$(a).filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() === 'Market Risk';
})
```

It returns an empty string.

```
var a = $("[nm='Sel_Team_ListB']")
$(a).find("div:contains('Market Risk')", "[class^='mstrmojo-ListBox-item']")
```

This one is the closest, yet it returns all the parent nodes of the one I'm after as well.

How to do this properly? Thanks.

Comment: Assuming you're looking for the class and context of a single element, you need to combine the selectors: `$('div[class^="mstrmojo-ListBox-item"]:contains("Market Risk")');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, you are setting second argument as [context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context)

Where as you need to combine the selectors.

```
$("div:contains('Market Risk')[class^='mstrmojo-ListBox-item']")
```